# Karma + Jasmine results in repeat warning WARN: 'Env: not supported, default to development'

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am running tests with Karma and jasmine on node to test angularjs controllers. 
My console gets spammed full of the following message

```
WARN: 'Env:  not supported, default to development'
```

I cannot seem to track this down, or find this error listed in any docs.

This seems to be coming from phantomjs.launcher, increasing log levels got this

```
DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: Env:  not supported, default to development
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable `NODE_ENV` to development?

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that but it was the first thing I tried. I assumed that was the issue. It did not change anything.